# How to build cocoa touch frameworks with existing static libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I'm trying to build a cocoa touch framework with existing static libraries in Xcode 6. I've linked all the necessary static libraries in the "Other Linker Flags" option, and the framework builds.

However, the size of the framework is way too small so it definitely doesn't seem like it's been built correctly. Also, I have a lot of missing symbols that should of been included from the static libraries.

Does anyone have any knowledge regarding how to build a cocoa touch framework with existing static libraries? What settings do I need to include all symbols from all static libraries into my framework?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one library file (.a) you have to do the following:

- Create a "Cocoa touch framework" in Xcode 6.
- Add the headers files.
- Add the library file (.a).
- Add an aggregate target.
- Select "Aggregate target" and in "Build Phases" add "New Run Script Phase".
- Post this content to script:

> ```
> ######################
> # Options
> ######################
>
> FRAMEWORK_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}"
> SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
> DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
> UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"
> FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
>
> ######################
> # Build Frameworks
> ######################
>
> xcodebuild -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator 2>&1
>
> xcodebuild -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -sdk iphoneos -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos 2>&1
>
> ######################
> # Create directory for universal
> ######################
>
> rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"
> mkdir "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"
> mkdir "${FRAMEWORK}"
>
> ######################
> # Copy files Framework
> ######################
>
> cp -r "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/." "${FRAMEWORK}"
>
> ######################
> # Make an universal binary
> ######################
>
> lipo "${PROJECT_DIR}/YOURFOLDER/YOURLIBRARY.a" -create -output "${FRAMEWORK}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" | echo
> open "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/"
> ```

- To generate the framework compiles the new target for the device

Answer (score 0):

You should create an Aggregate target, following the steps above.

And then select the aggregate target => Build Settings => Mach-O Type, change the Dynamic Library to Static Library. This option determine if your framework includes the symbols of your static libraries.

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic library work only for ios 8. If you need to use the dynamic library your project , add the your frameworks both Linked Frameworks and Libraries and Embedded Binaries in General Tab. Its will be work.

You can change the static library instead of dynamic library. Build setting -> Mach-O -> Static libarary, as well as change the deployment target as iOS 7.0. After changed these two done in your framework is work on iOS 7.0 and later. And then include your static library to link binary with libraries.